# Как привести большой xml файл в читабельный вид?

Tags: php, python, linux, xml, perl

Есть файл XML размером 400мб, который нужно привести в читабельный вид.

К сожалению все консольные утилиты которые я нашел, предварительно загружают файл в память и не могут обработать мой файл.

Может у кого пример скрипта или консольная утилита для таких случаев?

Пробовал xmllint, вылетает через несколько секунд:

```
xmllint --format --shell in.xml > tmp.xml
```

Спасибо!

Comment: разбить его на части (по тегам повторяющимся),  обработать части xmllint-ом, слить их обратно в большой файл. можете через php попробовать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167062/best-way-to-process-large-xml-in-php да и впрочем через любой язык с поддержкой xml можно найти варианты lazy loading

Comment: Возможно, вам не нужно использовать аргумент --shell, проверьте

Comment: Возьмите какой-нибудь Sax-парсер. Или если умеете в C#, пойдёт `XmlReader`.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить ключ `--stream` к `xmllint`, как предлагают в комментарии к [этому](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9223662/767632) ответу

Comment: ну на php, кстати, тоже XMLReader есть, я в свое время большие файлы им разбирал... 
только я недопонял... вам его просто распарсить надо, или действительно текст отформатировать в читабельный вид?? т.е. действительно кто-то будет пол-гиговый xml глазами читать?

Comment: связанные вопросы: [How to pretty print XML from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16090869/4279) и [Using python ElementTree's itertree function and writing modified tree to output file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15399904/4279)

Answer (score 1):

1. Как привести большой xml файл в читабельный вид? Если я правильно
   понял первое что необходимо сделать - считать данные из этого файла, второе -  сформировать вывод, третье записать или вывести информацию
2. предварительно загружают файл в память и не могут обработать мой файл... Если я правильно понял, то основная проблема в том что файл слишком большой и не хватает памяти что бы его прочесть

Если я вас неправильно понял, то прошу дать уточняющую информацию и в таком случае скорректирую ответ, а если правильно понял, то предлагаю воспользоваться библиотекой [PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) Она была создана на основе библиотеки PHPExcel, которая была очень медленная, но поддерживала множество форматов, в том числе xml. Чем обусловлен выбор этой библиотеки? Она позволяет большие файлы читать порционно. Привожу пример кода автора по использованию библиотеки для чтения нескольких строк

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>PHPExcel Reader Example #11</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>PHPExcel Reader Example #11</h1>
<h2>Reading a Workbook in "Chunks" Using a Configurable Read Filter (Version 1)</h2>
```

```
   <?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Xls';
//  $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
//  $inputFileType = 'Xml';
//  $inputFileType = 'Ods';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example2.xls';

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter  */
class chunkReadFilter implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter
{
    private $_startRow = 0;

    private $_endRow = 0;

    /**
     * We expect a list of the rows that we want to read to be passed into the constructor.
     *
     * @param mixed $startRow
     * @param mixed $chunkSize
     */
    public function __construct($startRow, $chunkSize)
    {
        $this->_startRow = $startRow;
        $this->_endRow = $startRow + $chunkSize;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '')
    {
        //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that were configured in the constructor
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
/*  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

echo '<hr />';

/*  Define how many rows we want for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 20;

/*  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 240; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
    echo 'Loading WorkSheet using configurable filter for headings row 1 and for rows ',$startRow,' to ',($startRow + $chunkSize - 1),'<br />';
    /*  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter, passing in the limits on which rows we want to read  **/
    $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter($startRow, $chunkSize);
    /*  Tell the Reader that we want to use the new Read Filter that we've just Instantiated  **/
    $reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
    /*  Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);

    //  Do some processing here

    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
    var_dump($sheetData);
    echo '<br /><br />';
}

?>
```

```html
<body>
</html>
```

$chunkSize = 20; я считаю это слишком мало если у вас там строк так 1 000 000, то вполне можно будет брать по 25 000 строк - это примерно 25-30 секунд выполнения обработки. По сути о чем тут речь: Мы реализуем интерфейс фильтра, создаем метод проверки, указываем количество за раз считываемых строк $chunkSize, а в цикле указываем начальную и конечную строку. Получаем результат в виде массива  $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

добавлено минутой позже:
как видите формат файла выставлен жестко, но можно и автоматически

```
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($arr['FileName']);
$reader =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

добавлено 2 минутами позже:

чтобы быстро запустить библиотеку я скачал папку с содержимым под названием PhpSpreadsheet, поместил ее в папку PhpOffice
и сделал _autoload

```
//ini_set('include_path', '/var/www/main_lib');
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    function __autoload($class_name) {   
        try{
            require_once(str_replace( '\\', '/', $class_name ). '.php'); 
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo 'err/не удалось загрузить класс '.$class_name.' либо в php.ini не выставлен параметр include_path="/var/www/main_lib"';
        }
    }
```

Как вы уже догадались библиотека у меня лежит в папке /var/www/main_lib